# XAML image gets cut off

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

In XAML I'm trying to make a large image that's cut off as a background to slowly move across the screen until it reaches the images otherside. Problem is the image is always no bigger than the display even it was stretched out. So I'm left with a image that's the size of the screen moving off with a black background.

```
        <Image x:Name="background" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Width="1500" Stretch="Fill" MaxWidth="1500" MinWidth="1500">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="bgTranslate" X="0"></TranslateTransform>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
```

Comment: What is the parent control of the Image?

Comment: the parent is a grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Grid control arranges the Image with the available cell size. Then the Image control cuts off the parts of the image that are outside the arrange rectangle (and hence not visible), before any RenderTransform is applied.

A simple workaround is to put the Image in a Canvas, which arranges its child elements with their desired size:

```
<Grid ...>
    ...
    <Canvas Grid.Row="1">
        <Image x:Name="background" Width="1500">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="bgTranslate"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Canvas>
    ...
</Grid>
```